# React Native <Modal /> onDismiss not invoked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Based on the code below, I would expect to see 'onDismiss!' when I swipe down on the modal view.

When I swipe down on the modal view it does not invoke the provided function. I can't find any other React Native users experiencing this problem. I am using React Native version 0.60.6.

Am I using Modal the wrong way or is this a bug?

```
<Modal
  animationType="slide"
  presentationStyle="pageSheet"
  visible={showSetup}
  hardwareAccelerated
  onDismiss={() => alert('onDismiss!')}
  onRequestClose={() => alert('onRequestClose!')}
>
  <SetupView closeView={() => this.willClose()} />
</Modal>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you checked out the library from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854450/detect-swipe-left-in-react-native)? I'd imagine you could trigger ```onDismiss``` from within the modal with a swipe event handler.

Comment: @ChrisB I am familiar with the library but it seems a bit overkill for this. I just want to know when the the view is dismissed so I can set `showSetup` back to false so the modal view can be accessed again.

Comment: This does indeed appear to be a bug, I had the same issue (that re-clicking wasn't working due to incorrect functionality of the `onDismiss`). In my case I could solve it, by checking the visibility state in the action, and manually calling the closing action. It's important that you wait until the state is persisted though (with a timeout or the callback).

Completely unrelated .. but may I ask how you managed to get the black background color behind the pageSheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue on the React Native issue tracker accurately describes this issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26892

I hope it's fixed soon!

Comment: Their "fix" was to lock the ticket to prevent comments and not fix anything.

Answer (score 0):

Hey there you should try something like that

This is the code for the component rendered in my modal:

```
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        onPressOut={() => {
          this.refs.view_ref.measure((fx, fy, width, height, px, py) => {
            if (py === Dimensions.get('window').height) {
              this.props.hide(false);
            }
          });
        }}
      >
        <View style={styles.view} ref={'view_ref'}>
          <View style={styles.nav}>
            <Text style={styles.nav_title}>New Currency</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
                this.props.hide(false);
              }}
            >
              <Icon
                style={styles.nav_close}
                name={'close'}
                size={30}
                color={mode === 'dark' ? 'white' : 'black'}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

When wrapping the view you want to render in a TouchableWithoutFeedback, you get the "onPressOut" functionality. Then with this portion of code:

```
onPressOut={() => {
          this.refs.view_ref.measure((fx, fy, width, height, px, py) => {
            if (py === Dimensions.get('window').height) {
              this.props.hide(false);
            }
          });
        }}
```

you basically tell the view to listen on touch events happening at the top of the modal, thus it will be also executed when you swipe to dismiss

I was inspired by this answer: 
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26892#issuecomment-605516625

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with React Native, but I have found a workaround that works for me. Basically I have a `TouchableWithoutFeedback` fill the entire Modal. Then I use the `onPressOut` prop, which receives an `event` from which you can measure the `locationY`. What I have found is that if `locationY < 0`, the swipe was successful in dismissing the `Modal`, and in that case you can call `setModalVisible(false)`. Then, next time you want to re-show the `Modal`, it will work. Hope it helps!

```
<Modal animationType="slide" presentationStyle="pageSheet" visible={ modal }>
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPressOut={(e) => {
    if (e.nativeEvent.locationY < 0) {
      handleModal(false)
    }}
  >
    <View style={ styles.modalOuter }>
      <View style={ styles.modalInner }>
        <Text>Hi from Modal</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
</Modal>

// ...

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  modalInner: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 0,
    width: "100%",
    height: 400
  },
  modalOuter: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    height: "100%"
  }
});
```